# Fail to capture group at regex \[(.*)\]

Tags: java, regex

i have written a regex like this `\[(.*)\]`

after that i want to capture anything inside `\[`  and `\]`
but result return fail

example:
regex `\[(.*)\]`
String test: `\[\sqrt 3\]`
expect: `\sqrt 3`

Comment: Using a regex with what language?

Comment: @j0e3gan : i use this regex with java

      String regex = "\\\[(.*)\\\]"; 

      String s = "\\[\sqrt 3 \\]";

      Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
     
      s = s.replaceAll(regex, "$1");

      System.out.println(s);

Comment: That will not even compile: *error: illegal escape character*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make  `.*` present inside the capturing group to do a non-greedy match. In regex, you need to escape the backslash three more times inorder to match a literal `\` symbol.

```
String s = "\\[\\sqrt 3\\]";
System.out.println(s);
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\\\\\[(.*?)\\\\\\]").matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
\[\sqrt 3\]
\sqrt 3
```